# Mocking in Jest with different return values based on a parameter(s)

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm working on trying to find a solution to mocking with parameters and having said mock return a different value based on the parameter. I've come up with the below solution but it doesn't quite feel right despite working.

Any advice on accomplishing this in a cleaner way would be much appreciated.

```
jest.mock(
  'hooks/useResourceAttribute',
  () => (domain: string, type: string, id: string, attribute: string) => {
    let value: string = '';
    if (type === 'blah') {
      value = 'meh';
    }

    if (type === 'blah2') {
      value = 'meh2';
    }

    return {
      value,
      fetch: jest.fn(),
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? The question is not super clear

Comment: Apologies @LoremIpsum, my question is this: is there a cleaner solution for achieving this? Doing it like this makes my test files extra large and not very clean in my opinion.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/timkindberg/jest-when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more flexible way is to use Jest spy:

```
jest.mock('hooks/useResourceAttribute', () => jest.fn());
```

This way a value can be mocked on a per-need basis, this results in stricter tests:

```
const fetchMock = jest.fn();
...
useResourceAttribute.mockReturnedValue({ value: 'meh', fetch: fetchMock });
```

Jest built-in spies provide basic functionality. For more powerful spies/stubs Sinon still can be used with Jest, either on its own or via `jest-sinon`. Sinon allows for conditional stubs:

```
useResourceAttribute
  .withArgs('blah', sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any)
  .returns({ value: 'meh', fetch: fetchMock });

useResourceAttribute
  .withArgs('blah2', sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any)
  .returns({ value: 'meh2', fetch: fetchMock });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `calledWith(params...)` from `jest-mock-extended`:

```
const myMock = jest.fn();
...
myMock
   .calledWith(expectedValue)
   .mockResolvedValueOnce(yourValue)
```

```
jest: "^29.5.0"
jest-mock-extended: "^3.0.4"
```